# showing users' unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

i (rarely) have some questions that nobody wants-to / knows-how-to answer so it would be awesome if there would be a users' unanswered questions shown with other questions by the user.

usually there are very few of them, but a limit to 1-2 would also be cool and a time limit of over 7 days unanswered or something similar...

this would help 'advertise' these harder questions to more people and maybe they'd get answered sooner.

one idea is to have them below **related** questions.

what do you think?
thnx, looking forward to your thoughts.

Comment: Have you considered offering a bounty?

Comment: yes i did. somehow, still not helping :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want those questions listed next to another question of the very same user:

As the sites are about questions and answers, not about people: I don't see the need for this. And even more: I'm afraid that a few might abuse this by posting new questions just to get some attention for other questions.

(For a non-personal list of unanswered questions there is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered etcetera. For a specific user one could search for [`user:<id> answers:0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101055+answers%3A0).)

Comment: is that a joke lol? would people really post a question to maybe draw attention to their other one? seems crazy. i guess it is possible :p

Comment: No, @b0x0rz, it's not a joke. Just like *some* (but luckily really only a few) might edit their existing post [more than 45 times](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2123140/revisions) just to bump it... (But my main statement: it's not about users, it's about Q&A.)